# In python is there a way to check if a function is a "generator function" before calling it?

Tags: python, function, generator, coroutine

Lets say I have two functions:

```
def foo():
  return 'foo'

def bar():
  yield 'bar'
```

The first one is a normal function, and the second is a generator function. Now I want to write something like this:

```
def run(func):
  if is_generator_function(func):
     gen = func()
     gen.next()
     #... run the generator ...
  else:
     func()
```

What will a straightforward implementation of `is_generator_function()` look like? Using the `types` package I can test if  `gen` is a generator, but I wish to do so before invoking `func()`.

Now consider the following case:

```
def goo():
  if False:
     yield
  else:
     return
```

An invocation of `goo()` will return a generator. I presume that the python parser knows that the `goo()` function has a yield statement, and I wonder if it possible to get that information easily.

Thanks!

Comment: It's useful to note that if a function contains a `yield` statement, then a `return` statement inside that function is not permitted to have an argument. It has to be just `return` which terminates the generator. Good question!

Comment: Good point, `goo()` should not be valid, however it is, at least here (Python 2.6.2).

Comment: A note to current readers: @GregHewgill comment above is no longer right, now you can return with argument (which is passed on the value attr of the StopIteration)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> 
>>> def foo():
...   return 'foo'
... 
>>> def bar():
...   yield 'bar'
... 
>>> print inspect.isgeneratorfunction(foo)
False
>>> print inspect.isgeneratorfunction(bar)
True
```

- New in Python version 2.6

Comment: Just a 2014 comment thanking you for providing a 2011 answer on a 2009 question  :)

Comment: Thought this solved my problem, but it doesn't perfectly. If the function is a wrapped generator, such as `partial(generator_fn, somearg=somevalue)` then this won't be detected. Nor will a lambda used in a similar circumstance, such as `lambda x: generator_fun(x, somearg=somevalue)`. These actually work as expected; he code was experimenting with a helper function that can chain generators, but if a normal function is found, it'll wrap it in a "single item generator".

Comment: Just a 2020 comment appreciating that in 2014 you thanked him for providing a 2011 answer on a 2009 question.

Comment: Note that `inspect.isgeneratorfunction()` doesn't work for AsyncGenerator. Maybe time did a trick on that answer ? ;)

Comment: @CyrilN. `inspect.isasyncgenfunction()` exists for that. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isasyncgenfunction)

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> def foo():
...   return 'foo'
... 
>>> def bar():
...   yield 'bar'
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('bar')
              3 YIELD_VALUE         
              4 POP_TOP             
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

As you see, the key difference is that the bytecode for `bar` will contain at least one `YIELD_VALUE` opcode.  I recommend using the `dis` module (redirecting its output to a StringIO instance and checking its `getvalue`, of course) because this provides you a measure of robustness over bytecode changes -- the exact numeric values of the opcodes will change, but the disassembled symbolic value will stay pretty stable;-).

Comment: Alex, how do you feel about calling "blah = func()"... then checking if type(blah) is a generator? and if it's not, then func() was called already :-). I think that would have been how I would have first investigated how to do this :-).

Comment: Was about to write the same but the Python übergod came in first. :-)

Comment: The OP is very clear in the Q's title that he wants the information **before calling** -- showing how to get it **after** calling does not answer the given question with the clearly expressed constraints.

Comment: @paprika: Ha... I have no idea if this works... but Alex said it does... so +1 :-)... and I doubt anyone else will have a better answer... not even Guido himself.

Comment: @Alex: absolutely... I must say... I didn't read the question thoroughly :-o. Now I'm looking at it and it's obvious :-). I kind of focused on the "run" function and thought that could easily be done with types.

Comment: @paprika, tx for the kudos, but that title belongs to Guido van Rossum (who's not active on SO, AFAIK).  In the Python pantheon, I can at most be an Einherjar (gender issues precluding me being a Valkyrie;-).

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a decorator that hooks on the decorated function returned/yielded value. Its basic goes:

```
import types
def output(notifier):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            r = f(*args, **kwargs)
            if type(r) is types.GeneratorType:
                for item in r:
                    # do something
                    yield item
            else:
                # do something
                return r
    return decorator
```

It works because the decorator function is unconditionnaly called: it is the return value that is tested.

---

**EDIT:** Following the comment by Robert Lujo, I ended up with something like:

```
def middleman(f):
    def return_result(r):
        return r
    def yield_result(r):
        for i in r:
            yield i
    def decorator(*a, **kwa):
        if inspect.isgeneratorfunction(f):
            return yield_result(f(*a, **kwa))
        else:
            return return_result(f(*a, **kwa))
    return decorator
```

Comment: I had similar case and I got error: SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator. When I think about it, it looks logical, the same function can't be normal function and generator function in the same time. Does this really work in your case?