# How to check if an object is a generator object in Python?

Tags: python, generator

In Python, how do I check if an object is a generator object?

Trying

```
>>> type(myobject, generator)
```

gives the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'generator' is not defined
```

(I know I can check if the object has a `__next__` method for it to be a generator, but I want some way using which I can determine the type of any object, not just generators.)

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? Post more context, there may be a smarter way. Why do you need to know if it's a generator?

Comment: `from types import GeneratorType;type(myobject, GeneratorType)` will give you the proper result for objects of class 'generator'. But as Daenyth implies, that isn't necessarily the right way to go.

Comment: If you're checking for `__next__`, you're actually accepting any iterator, not just generators - which is very likely what you want.

Comment: Oh, slight correction to my previous comment: that should probably be `isinstance(myobject, GeneratorType)`.

Comment: As often as not, the real point of knowing whether something is a generator is to be able to avoid them, on account of desiring to iterate over the same collection multiple times.

Comment: For people wondering about the use case, this could be useful when you need to know if the iterator will be consumed (eg if your function accepts any iterator but needs to iterate more than once, you'll want to materialize it before iterating)

Answer (score 309, accepted):

You can use [`GeneratorType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.GeneratorType) from `types`:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.GeneratorType
<class 'generator'>
>>> gen = (i for i in range(10))
>>> isinstance(gen, types.GeneratorType)
True
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work for generator classes (for example, map or filter objects).

Comment: Perhaps `isinstance(gen, (types.GeneratorType, map, filter))` is useful to also detect `map` and `filter`. This will still not include other iterables and iterators though.

Comment: isinstance({1:2}.values(),types.GeneratorType)==False

Comment: @RicardoMagalhãesCruz that is not a "generator class". There is no such thing as a "generator class". You are talking about *iterators*, but being an iterator is **not a type**, it simply means you implement the iterator protocol, i.e. define `__iter__` and `__next__`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for async generators `type: <async_generator object Service.continue at 0x7f1cce523dc0>`
`isinstance(result, types.GeneratorType)` -> False.

Answer (score 51):

You mean generator functions ? use [`inspect.isgeneratorfunction`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isgeneratorfunction).

**EDIT :**

if you want a generator object you can use [inspect.isgenerator](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isgenerator) as pointed out by JAB in his comment.

Comment: generator function is not generator object; see @utdemir's answer

Comment: @Piotr: In which case you use [`inspect.isgenerator`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isgenerator).

Comment: @JAB, @Piotr: Reflected to address all the possibilities of what the OP can mean , thanks JAB :)

Comment: Note: if you only need this test, you can avoid a small overhead by using [**@utdemir** solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6416585/248390) because `inspect.isgenerator` is only a shorthand to: [`isinstance(object, types.GeneratorType)`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/44590c1b264e/Lib/inspect.py#l164).

Comment: See @RobertLujo answer for distinction between generator object and generator function. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32380774/3595112

Comment: While not OP's question (so no upvote), I came here while searching for _exactly_ this answer but this page came up as the best alternative search result.  Wanted to know if a given function is a generator function.

Answer (score 45):

I think it is important to make distinction between **generator functions** and **generators** (generator function's result):

```
>>> def generator_function():
...     yield 1
...     yield 2
...
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.isgeneratorfunction(generator_function)
True
```

calling generator_function won't yield normal result, it even won't execute any code in the function itself, the result will be special object called **[generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)**:

```
>>> generator = generator_function()
>>> generator
<generator object generator_function at 0x10b3f2b90>
```

so it is not generator function, but generator:

```
>>> inspect.isgeneratorfunction(generator)
False

>>> import types
>>> isinstance(generator, types.GeneratorType)
True
```

and generator function is not generator:

```
>>> isinstance(generator_function, types.GeneratorType)
False
```

just for a reference, actual call of function body will happen by consuming generator, e.g.:

```
>>> list(generator)
[1, 2]
```

See also [In python is there a way to check if a function is a "generator function" before calling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871685/in-python-is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-function-is-a-generator-function-before)

Answer (score 17):

The [`inspect.isgenerator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isgenerator) function is fine if you want to check for pure generators (i.e. objects of class "generator"). However it will return `False` if you check, for example, a [`zip` iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). An alternative way for checking for a generalised generator is to use this function:

```
def isgenerator(iterable):
    return hasattr(iterable, '__iter__') and not hasattr(iterable, '__len__')
```

Comment: Hmm. This returns true for `x=iter([1,2])`. Seems to me it's really testing whether or not an object is an **iterator**, not a generator. But maybe "iterator" is exactly what you mean by "generalised generator".

Comment: My favorite solution, though it should be noted that it doesn't count `range` as a generator (technically correct), but annoying for me as `range` has a different type py2 vs 3

Comment: dict.values() is generator  ,but has` __len__`

Answer (score 9):

You could use the Iterator or more specifically, the Generator from the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#module-typing) module.

```
from typing import Generator, Iterator
g = (i for i in range(1_000_000))
print(type(g))
print(isinstance(g, Generator))
print(isinstance(g, Iterator))
```

#### result:

```
<class 'generator'>
True
True
```

Comment: +1 for a working solution. This being said, the docs for the `typing.TypeVar` class seem to discourage the use of `isinstance` in conjunction with the `typing` module: "At runtime, `isinstance(x, T)` will raise `TypeError`. In general, `isinstance()` and `issubclass()` should not be used with types."

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.Generator  Deprecated since version 3.9

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to import a module, you can declare an object for comparison at the beginning of the program:

```
gentyp = type(1 for i in "")
# ...
type(myobject) == gentyp
```

Comment: I like this one because it's so self-contained and obvious once it is explained.

Comment: Also, it works in micropython !

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> 
>>> def foo():
...   yield 'foo'
... 
>>> print inspect.isgeneratorfunction(foo)
True
```

Comment: This works only if it is a function. If 'foo' is a generator object, it shows 'False'. See my question, I want to make checks for generator objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using tornado webserver or similar you might have found that server methods are actually generators and not methods. This makes it difficult to call other methods because yield is not working inside the method and therefore you need to start managing pools of chained generator objects. A simple method to manage pools of chained generators is to create a help function such as

```
def chainPool(*arg):
    for f in arg:
      if(hasattr(f,"__iter__")):
          for e in f:
             yield e
      else:
         yield f
```

Now writing chained generators such as

```
[x for x in chainPool(chainPool(1,2),3,4,chainPool(5,chainPool(6)))]
```

Produces output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Which is probably what you want if your looking to use generators as a thread alternative or similar.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can check if the object has a next method for it to be a generator, but I want some way using which I can determine the type of any object, not just generators.

Don't do this.  It's simply a very, very bad idea.

Instead, do this:

```
try:
    # Attempt to see if you have an iterable object.
    for i in some_thing_which_may_be_a_generator:
        # The real work on `i`
except TypeError:
     # some_thing_which_may_be_a_generator isn't actually a generator
     # do something else
```

In the unlikely event that the body of the **for** loop also has `TypeError`s, there are several choices: (1) define a function to limit the scope of the errors, or (2) use a nested **try** block.

Or (3) something like this to distinguish all of these `TypeError`s which are floating around.

```
try:
    # Attempt to see if you have an iterable object.
    # In the case of a generator or iterator iter simply 
    # returns the value it was passed.
    iterator = iter(some_thing_which_may_be_a_generator)
except TypeError:
     # some_thing_which_may_be_a_generator isn't actually a generator
     # do something else
else:
    for i in iterator:
         # the real work on `i`
```

Or (4) fix the other parts of your application to provide generators appropriately.  That's often simpler than all of this.

Comment: Your solution will catch TypeErrors thrown by the body of the for loop. I've proposed an edit that would prevent this undesirable behaviour.

Comment: This is the more Pythonic way of doing it, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Although, if you are iterating over a list of items and more of them are not iterators than are iterators then this could take longer surely?

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: Exceptions are faster than `if` statements.  And.  That kind of micro-optimization is a waste of time.  Fix the algorithm that produces a mixed bag of iterators and non-iterators to produce only iterators and save yourself all of this pain.

Comment: This would mistakenly assume any iterable as a generator.

Comment: primitives which are typically not intended to be iterated in this sort of code, like strings, and bytes, are an exception to the "this is iterable" logic.  basically this is "supposed to be pythonic"... but almost never works in practice.   not the least of which is that python exceptions are often not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little old question, however I was looking for similar solution for myself, but for async generator class, so you may find this helpful.

Based on [utdemir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472416/utdemir) reply:

```
import types
isinstance(async_generator(), types.AsyncGeneratorType)
```