# assertions on a generator object

Tags: python, unit-testing, generator, assertion

*are there techniques for introspecting generator objects (e.g. for assertions in unit tests)?*

more specifically, i have a data processing pipeline comprised of a sequence of small functions applied to values often inside list comprehensions or generator expressions, like so:

generate some random data:

```
>>> raw_data = ["${}".format(RND.randint(10, 100)) for c in range(10)]

>>> # a function that does some sort of of transform
>>> fnx = lambda q: float(q.replace('$', ''))

>>> d1 = [fnx(itm) for itm in raw_data]
```

in a next step, another transform function will be applied over the items of **d1**, and so on.

in the case just above, assertions for instance, on the length of **prices_clean**, or on the min/max of its values, etc, are the heart of my unit test suite:

```
>>> assert len(d1) == 10
```

given that i am just going to iterate through these intermediate results, i don't actually need a list, a generator object will do, and given the much lower memory profile, that's what i use:

```
>>> d1 = (fnx(itm) for itm in raw_data)
```

of course the assertions i rely on when using list comprehensions are not available for generator objects:

```
>>> d1
  <generator object <genexpr> at 0x106da9230>

>>> assert len(d1) == 10
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    assert len(d1) == 10
  TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

if i have to call **list()** on the generator object just for an assert then my test suite runs very slowly (with the unfortunate practical result that debs often don't run it at all).

i have looked at the attributes of generator objects for any that i can usefully introspect, but i didn't see how i can use often them in the way i have described here.

Comment: Generator objects are actually functions and don't know in advance how many results they're going to return. There's no way to get the "length" of a generator other than actually consuming it.

Comment: If you want to examine the sequence generated then simply do `the_sequence = list(the_generator)` and then do all the asserts on `the_sequence`. This avoids calling `list` for every *single* assert(since you can assert both length, and contents in a single run).

Answer (score 5):

[Reference for Type checking of a Generator object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416585/452708)

```
import types
self.assertIsInstance(_result_generator, types.GeneratorType)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @thg435 commented, without consuming it, you don't know the length of the generator.

Usually I do one of following:

In case the generator produce small number of elements:

```
assert len(list(d1)) == 10
```

or

```
assert sum(1 for x in d1) == 10
```