# How can I group the items in a list according to a "key" in the list elements?

Tags: python, list, tuples, grouping

I have some list that consist of a tuples like this

```
one = [(4, 'a'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (5, 'e'), (6, 'f')]
```

and i want to group item on list one based on that integer to create new array that has an output like this

```
final = [(g1, 2, ['c']), (g2, 3, ['b','d']), (g3, 4, ['a']), (g4, 5, ['e']), (g5, 6, ['f'])]
```

I have no idea in creating the final list. How is python doing that? Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

**Note:** g1, g2, and so on is just some string with increment.

Comment: Is the order important to you? and what are `g1`, `g2`...?

Comment: Ya, that is what makes me confused. I should order the list. And g1, g2, g3 is just some string with increment value. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where did `2, ['a']` and `5, ['f']` come from?

Comment: That is my fault, I mean (g1, 2, ['c']) and (g5, 6, ['f']). Edited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you want the output to be sorted, you can sort the original list based on the first element

```
>>> first = lambda x: x[0]
>>> one_sorted = sorted(one, key=first)
```

then you can group the elements based on the first elements with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), like this

```
groupby(one_sorted, first)
```

since you want to assign numbers, in ascending order, to the groups, you can wrap it with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) like this

```
enumerate(groupby(one_sorted, first), 1)
```

then you can [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the result of `enumerate` in a `for` loop, like this

```
for index, (item, group) in enumerate(groupby(one_sorted, first), 1)
```

now you just have to construct the result list. You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to do that, like this

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [(index, item, [j[1] for j in group])
...     for index, (item, group) in enumerate(groupby(one_sorted, first), 1)]
[(1, 2, ['c']), (2, 3, ['b', 'd']), (3, 4, ['a']), (4, 5, ['e']), (5, 6, ['f'])]
```

`[j[1] for j in group]` actually iterates the grouped items and fetches the second item, which is the actual string.

---

Alternatively, you can group the elements in a dictionary, like this

```
>>> groups = {}
>>> for number, string in one:
...     groups.setdefault(number, []).append(string)
...     
... 
>>> groups
{2: ['c'], 3: ['b', 'd'], 4: ['a'], 5: ['e'], 6: ['f']}
```

and then return apply the `enumerate` on the sorted dictionary, like this

```
>>> [(index, number, groups[number])
...     for index, number in enumerate(sorted(groups), 1)]
[(1, 2, ['c']), (2, 3, ['b', 'd']), (3, 4, ['a']), (4, 5, ['e']), (5, 6, ['f'])]
```

Comment: [(index, item, [j[1] for j in group]) for index, (item, group) in enumerate(groupby(one_sorted, first), 1)] that's work like a charm. But I do not understand, you constructed that list like a pro, lol. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, i am sorry it'll be OOT but I want to know how if we doesn't sort the first list? I mean, we just 'group' that list. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default dict to group the items:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# create dictionary # {2: ['c'], 3: ['b', 'd'], 4: ['a'], ...}
groups = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in one:
    groups[k].append(v)

# create sorted list [(1, (2, ['c'])), (2, (3, ['b', 'd'])), (3, (4, ['a'])), ...]
lists = enumerate(sorted(list(groups.items())), 1)
```

---

**Note:** The above produces an enumerator, which is generator-like object [(see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23663453/1290264)). If you want to convert to a normal list just replace the last line with:

```
lists = [(i,k,v) for i,(k,v) in enumerate(sorted(list(groups.items())), 1)]
```

Comment: Promising, I printed lists and give me error "<enumerate object at 0x107fb8280>". Thank you

Comment: @SonicMaster it's not an error. It's printing the enumerator object reference. However, if you need a list I've updated the answer to show how to convert to a normal list.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to create a dictionary from int -> list. Go through the original list, if the int is a key then just add it to its list otherwise create a list with its value and add it to the dictionary.