# Why do the enumerate, zip, range types not belong to types.GeneratorType?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, generator

Python 3 has introduced generator-like objects to be returned upon calling `range()` and `zip()`. The object returned acts like a generator and can be iterated through once but doesn't 'print' well, much like the `enumerate()` return argument.

I was perplexed to see, however, that they are distinct object types and do not belong to `types.GeneratorType`, or at least this is what the `types` module shows. A function that would run e.g. expecting a generator would not detect them. What is their inheritance? Do they belong to a main "generator" structure, so that they e.g. could be identified along with other generators?

```
import types

a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

# create some generator-type objects
obj_zip = zip(a,b)
obj_enu = enumerate(a)
obj_r = range(10)

print(type(obj_zip))
print(type(obj_enu))
print(type(obj_r))

# checking against types.GeneratorType returns False
print(isinstance(obj_zip,types.GeneratorType))
print(isinstance(obj_enu,types.GeneratorType))
print(isinstance(obj_r,types.GeneratorType))

# checking against their own distinct object types returns True
print(isinstance(obj_zip,zip))
```

Comment: `range` objects aren't a generator, they're an immutable sequence type; you can iterate them repeatedly, so they definitely shouldn't be of `GeneratorType`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [the `GeneratorType` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.GeneratorType):

> #### types.GeneratorType
>
> > The type of generator-iterator objects, created by generator functions.

Generator functions are a specific thing in the language; it means functions that use `yield` or `yield from` (or generator expressions, which are just a shorthand for inline generator functions). It's a subset of the set of iterators (all things that you can call `next()` on to get a new value), which is in turn a subset of iterables (all things that you can call `iter()` on to get an iterator; iterators themselves are iterables, where `iter(iterator)` behaves as the identity function).

Basically, if you're testing for "can I loop over this?", test `isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Iterable)`. If you're checking "is this an exhaustible iterator?" (that is, will I exhaust it by looping over it?), test either `isinstance(obj, collections.abc.Iterator)` or for the duck-typing based approach, test `iter(obj) is obj` (the invariants on iterators *require* that `iter(iterator)` yield the original iterator object unchanged).

Note that `range` is *not* a generator or iterator. Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range):

> Rather than being a function, range is actually an immutable sequence type, as documented in [Ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) and [Sequence Types — list, tuple, range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

Being an immutable sequence type means it *is* an iterable, but that's it. The fact that it is usually used as if it were an iterator is irrelevant; if it were an iterator, the second loop here would never execute:

```
r = range(3)
for i in r:
    print("First", i)
for i in r:
    print("Second", i)
```

but it works just fine, because each (implicit) call to `iter(r)` returns a *new* itera*tor* based on the same underlying itera*ble*.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I wanted, a clarification between Iterable, Iterator and Generator. So `enumerate()` and `zip()` create **iterators** (i.e. that can be exhausted) but not **generators**.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that enumerate is *functionally* equivalent to a generator. Actually it is implemented in C and returns an iterator, not a generator as described in [Does enumerate() produce a generator object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23663453/246241). 
Generators and iterables are almost the same. This is explained in detail in [Difference between Python's Generators and Iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2776865/246241).

I'm assuming you're trying to solve a real problem, like finding out if you can iterate over something. To solve that you can test if something is  an instance of `collections.Iterable`.

```
a = enumerate([1,2,3])
isinstance(a, collections.Iterable)
>>> True
```

Comment: "iterable" as a category is a superset of "generator" (all generators are iterable, but not all iterables are generators), so that's not all that useful.

Comment: Well I am trying to create a function that is running over iterables twice. So, in case the iterable is a generator, it tries to clone a generator (using `itertools.tee`), but I'm having a problem checking against generators if the object passed belongs to these generator-type objects that have a special type.

Answer (score 0):

not meant to be a full answer ([ShadowRanger answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52970756/6451573) already explains everything) but just to state that `types.GeneratorType` is really a very limited type as shown in `types.py` source:

```
def _g():
    yield 1
GeneratorType = type(_g())
```

it only scopes the type of generator functions. Other "generator-like" objects don't use `yield` so they're not a match.