# Why can you not create a dictionary from an enumerated data set after you print it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, enumerate

I was practising with `enumerate()` and dictionaries in python. When I do not print out the enumerated data I am able to create a dictionary from the enumerated data. But when I do print out the enumerated data, I am no longer able to create a dictionary. Why would that be?

For when I do not print out my enumerated data:

```
data = ['a','b','c','d']

enum_data = enumerate(data, 1)

data_dict = dict(enum_data)
print("Data Dict: ", data_dict)

print("Should be 'a': ", data_dict.get(1))
```

My output is

```
Data Dict:  {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
Should be 'a':  a
```

But when I do not:

```
data = ['a','b','c','d']

enum_data = enumerate(data, 1)
for enum, point in enum_data:
    print("Count: ", enum, " ", "Element: ", point)

data_dict = dict(enum_data)
print("Data Dict: ", data_dict)

print("Should be 'a': ", data_dict.get(1))
```

I get:

```
Count:  1   Element:  a
Count:  2   Element:  b
Count:  3   Element:  c
Count:  4   Element:  d
Data Dict:  {}
Should be 'a':  None
```

Comment: Related content: [Does enumerate() produce a generator object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663231/does-enumerate-produce-a-generator-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns an iterator. An iterator [may only be iterated over once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data).

A common solution is to use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to return an arbitrary number of independent iterators:

```
from itertools import tee

data = ['a','b','c','d']

enum_data1, enum_data2 = tee(enumerate(data, 1), 2)
for enum, point in enum_data1:
    print("Count: ", enum, " ", "Element: ", point)

data_dict = dict(enum_data2)

print("Data Dict: ", data_dict)  # {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
print("Should be 'a': ", data_dict.get(1))  # a
```