# python isinstance(obj, tpyes.GeneratorType) fails

Tags: python, generator, spacy

If I check types `types.GeneratorType` and the generator object `text[0]` each, both returns `<class 'generator'>`. However, whenever I use `isinstance()`, it returns `False`. What am I doing wrong?

```
import types
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')
text = [nlp(' '.join(docs)).sents]

print(types.GeneratorType)

Out[27]: <class 'generator'>


print(text)
Out[28]: [<generator object at 0x000001F4407F8950>]

print(type(text[0]))
Out[29]: <class 'generator'>


print(isinstance(text[0], types.GeneratorType))
Out[30]: False
```

Comment: What do you get for `type(text[0]) == types.GeneratorType`?

Comment: What is the result of `types.GeneratorType is type(text[0])`? Second, why do you need to do this?

Comment: If the output you are showing is correct, then I think this should definitely work, we can't directly test this to reproduce it though

Comment: The presence of `Out[27]` is suspicious to me.... is there more code we aren't seeing? Have you run this as solo script?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little confusing to read, because the variable `text` is a list containing a generator object. But I think what you're seeing here comes down to a fairly subtle distinction: [the difference between generator functions and generators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32380774/6400719) in Python.

```
import types
import inspect

def generator_function():
    for i in range(100):
        yield i

generator = (i for i in range(100))

isinstance(generator_function, types.GeneratorType)  # False
isinstance(generator, types.GeneratorType)  # True

inspect.isgeneratorfunction(generator_function)  # True
inspect.isgeneratorfunction(generator)  # False
```

spaCy's `Doc.sents` property is a generator function that yields sentence spans – [see here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/14d9007efd2ca457c6e6549d5599e460e198904c/spacy/tokens/doc.pyx#L515) for the implementation.