# lazy evaluation in Python3

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation

Suppose I have a function with side effects (in the example, the side effect is that something is printed).  Is there any version of the any() or any construction of the the list iterable which would NOT trigger side effects after finding a True result?

Example, suppose this function:

```py
def a(x):
   print("A function got: " + str(x))
   return x == 2
```

One might **hope** that this call would do the trick.  Of course, it does not:

```py
any([
  a(i) for i in range(5)
])
```

Which prints:

```
A function got: 0
A function got: 1
A function got: 2
A function got: 3
A function got: 4
```

But I would like it to print this instead:

```
A function got: 0
A function got: 1
A function got: 2
```

Why?  Range is an iterable, the list comprehension is producing an iterable, I would sort of expect Python to chain those together and stop executing the whole thing as soon as the any() function stops consuming, which it should do once it reaches the first True.

What am I misunderstanding?  What version of this would behave in this way, if any?

Comment: Um... don't use a list comprehension?

Comment: Call `any(a(i) for i in range(5))`, without `[` and `]`. With the brackets, you are creating a list comprehension, so first it is creating a list with all the elements produced by the generator and then passing it through `any`. Without the brackets, `any` just iterates as many elements in the generator as necessary.

Comment: Wow. That construction is so great! I did not know. I'm going to use that all over the place now.  What a difference a few square brackets makes. mind blown.  Can you paste this as an answer @jdehesa ?

Comment: @BillHuneke It's fine, take the one that is already posted as accepted, no need to have duplicate answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you use a list, all the values are evaluated. The only way to get lazy evaluation is to keep it as an iterator. You can do this with a generator comprehension:

```
any(a(i) for i in range(5))
```

To be clear, using the brackets is the same as doing `any(list(a(i) for i in range(5)))`.

Comment: Not quite true, `any(map(a, range(5))` is lazy without generator.

Comment: @HeapOverflow How come? `map` is a generator... It is just like writing `any(a(i) for i in range(5))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo What makes you think it's a generator?

Comment: [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map): *Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable, yielding the results*

Comment: @Tomerikoo That doesn't say anything about it being a generator.

Comment: *__yielding__ the result*

Comment: @HeapOverflow `map` was a function that returned a list in Python 2; in Python 3 it is a *type* that implements the iterator protocol, calling `a` on demand as a value is requested from the `map` value.

Comment: @Tomerikoo That doesn't mean it's a generator. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6416585/12671057).

Comment: @chepner Yes. And? What does that have to do with generators?

Comment: A `map` is a generator (in the colloquial sense of generating values), but it is not a `generator` (which is the Python type created by generator expressions and generator functions).

Comment: @HeapOverflow: `any(map(a, range(5))` is indeed lazy. It won't get interpreted until you write the missing `)`.

Comment: @EricDuminil Darn, I had even specifically looked at the parentheses and somehow convinced myself that there are enough :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's right. It's important that it's kept as an iterator to be lazy. I suppose I meant that a generator comprehension is required over a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply run the loop and `break` out of it:

```
for i in range(5):
    if a(i):
        break
```

So

```
def my_any(func, it):
    for i in it:
        if func(i):
            break

my_any(a, range(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

another valid solution is as follow first import from itertool takewhile then,

```
l=list(takewhile(lambda x:a(x) is False, range(5)))
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use below code by adding condition inside your list comprehension

```
def a(x):
   print("A function got: " + str(x))

any([
  a(i) for i in range(5) if i<3 
])
```

Comment: This assumes, that you know the return condition and can directly apply it to the data. In this extremely simple example this might work, but `a(x)` might be a large calculation which you cannot expect to know in advance (this is why you have it as a function in the first place). This answer completely misses the point of the question...

Comment: Also, the question is not about **HOW** to achieve the desired output, but more as to **WHY** we get the actual one