# Does the builtin open() return a generator?

Tags: python

This is a question about the correct terminology used for "generators". Let's look at the file object returned by the builtin function `open()`.

### 1. The builtin `open()` function, official documentation

In the [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), then `open()` function is said to return a "file object" and the [documentation for file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) does not really say what kind of creature this is, other than  it has `read()` and `write()` methods and that

> File objects are also called file-like objects or streams.

‍♂️ *Well that's helpful, right?*

### 2. Words from the internet

Here are some examples where the file object returned by the `open()` is called a generator.

#### 2.1. [How to Use Generators and yield in Python (Realpython.com)](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)

*(emphasis mine)*

> open() returns a **generator object** that you can lazily iterate through line by line

#### 2.2. [Lazy Method for Reading Big File in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519633/lazy-method-for-reading-big-file-in-python)

*(Accepted answer with 400+ score, emphasis mine)*

> If the file is line-based, the file object is already a lazy **generator**
> of lines:
>
> ```
> for line in open('really_big_file.dat'):
>     process_data(line)
> ```

#### 2.3. [Generators in Python — 5 Things to Know (medium.com)](https://medium.com/swlh/generators-in-python-5-things-to-know-c76a1f60427a)

*(emphasis mine)*

> using the `open()` method to open the EEG file will create a file
> object, which functions as a **generator** that yields a line of data as
> string each time.

One can probably find easily more of such examples from everywhere on the Internet..

### 3. Testing if file object returned by `open()` is a generator

Following the [How to check if an object is a generator object in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416538/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-generator-object-in-python) we can form few test for the file object:

```py
In [7]: o = open(r'C:\tmp\test.csv')

In [8]: type(o)
Out[8]: _io.TextIOWrapper

In [9]: import inspect

In [10]: inspect.isgenerator(o)
Out[10]: False

In [12]: inspect.isgeneratorfunction(o)
Out[12]: False

In [13]: import types

In [14]: isinstance(o, types.GeneratorType)
Out[14]: False
```

All of these tests fail, hinting that the file object returned by `open()` is not a generator. Still, many people tend to call it a generator.

#### 4. Generators included – or not?

So, fellow pythonistas, is it correctly said that `open()` function returns a generator? And does the following

```
for line in open('file.csv'):
    do_something(line)
```

involve usage of generators?

Comment: Since you can `seek` an open file: clearly not.

Comment: The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/942f7a2dea2e95a0fa848329565c0d0288d92e47/Lib/_pyio.py#L2537) for the `__next__` method of the `TextIoWrapper` says that `TextIoWrapper` is subclass of `TextIoBase`, which is subclass of `IOBase`. It [also says](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/942f7a2dea2e95a0fa848329565c0d0288d92e47/Lib/_pyio.py#L338) that "IOBase object can be iterated over *yielding* the lines in a
    stream.".  There they use the term "yield". Would it say that there is some generator involved when reading the lines using `for line in open(file)`?

Comment: In that paragraph it explicitly uses the word *iterator*, not generator. The word “yield” is likely used in the English sense, not in the Python-keyword sense.

Comment: You can also do: `l = [1, 2, 3] ; for num in l: ...` That doesn't make the list a generator, it is an **iterable**. Just like the file object. You can use it to *behave* like a generator, but the difference is as said above, you can `seek` back on a file. You **can't** rewind a generator

Comment: It makes sense. I checked the source code of the `TextIOWrapper` and it seems that in addition of being an iterable it is also an *iterator* (it has `__iter__` method that returns `self`).

Answer (score 1):

The python `open` function returns a [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) object which is not a generator.

The reason why you can iterate through the object though is because it defines the `__next__` method.
You can find the source code for it [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/942f7a2dea2e95a0fa848329565c0d0288d92e47/Lib/_pyio.py#L2537), it will help clear things out.

Comment: Thanks! See my comment on the question; There is a mention about "IOBase object can be iterated over *yielding *the lines in a stream.". Would this say that there is a generator involved when using `for line in open(file): ..`?

Comment: @np8 I linked the source code with my answer, the `IOBase` class does not define a `__next__` method. The word yielding in the documentation is referring to subclasses of the `IOBase` class and does not imply a generator involved.

Comment: The direct return type of open is a `TextIOWrapper`, it is not a generator.