# `isinstance` with non-conventional classinfo

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, typechecking

##### *Disclaimer*:

unlike 99.9% of most out there, I didn't pick up python until very late in the progression of languages I write in. I won't harp on some of the odd behaviors of the import model, but I do find myself having an issue understanding why the `type` checking (ie: "what kinda thing is you random object some user has given me hmm?) is all over the place.

Really this is just checking what class of data a thing is, but in python it's never struck me as being straightforward and in my research on the interwebz, well let's just say their are *opinions* and the only thing anyone agrees on is using the term `pythonic`. My question boils down to `type(x) == y` vs `isinstance(x, y)` when the `type` isn't one of the more straightforward `list, tuple, float, int, ...` yadda yadda .

---

##### *Current Conundrum*:

I need the ability to determine if an object that is being passed(either directly, or dynamically within a recursive routine) is *not just an iterable*, but more specifically an object created by `scandir`. Please don't get lost in the singular issue, i'll show i have many ways to get to this, but the bigger question is:
A) Is the method I'm using to coerce the output of `type()` going to bite me in the backside given a case I am not thinking of?
B) Am I missing a simpler way of accessing the 'class|type' of an object that is language-specific type of thing?
C) TBD

I'll start by showing maybe where the root of my disconnect comes from, and have a little fun with the people I know will take the time to answer this question properly by a first example in `R`.

I'm going to cast my own `class` attribute just to show what i'm talking about:

```
> a <- 1:3
> class(a)
[1] "integer"
> attr(a, "class")
[1] "integer"
```

Ok so, like in python, we can ask if this is an `int(eger)` etc. Now I can re-class as I see fit, which is getting to the point of where i'm going with the python issue:

```
> class(a) <- "i.can.reclass.how.i.want"
> class(a)
[1] "i.can.reclass.how.i.want"
> attr(a, "class")
[1] "i.can.reclass.how.i.want"
```

So now in python, let's say I have a `data.frame`, or as you all put it `DataFrame`:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3]})
>>> type(df)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Ok, so if i want to determine if my object is a `DataFrame`:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3]})
# Get the mro of type(df)? and remove 'object' as an item in the mro tuple
>>> isinstance(df, type(df).__mro__[:-1])
True
# hmmmm
>>> isinstance(df, (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame))
NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined
# hmmm.. aight let's try..
>>> isinstance(df, (pd.core.frame.DataFrame))
True
# Lulz... alright then, I guess i get that, but why did __mro__ pass with pandas vs pd? Not the point...
```

---

##### *For when you can't do that*

```py
# yes..i know.. 3.5+ os.scandir... focus on bigger picture of this question/issue
import scandir

>>> a = scandir.scandir("/home")

>>> type(a)
posix.ScandirIterator

>>> str(type(scandir.scandir("/home")))
"<class 'scandir.ScandirIterator'>"

>>> isinstance(scandir.scandir("/home"), (scandir,scandir.ScandirIterator))
AttributeError: module 'scandir' has no attribute 'ScandirIterator'

# Okay fair enough.. kinda thought it could work like pandas, maybe can but I can't find it?
```

### Question:

Does that mean that my only way of knowing the `instance/type` of certain objects like the `scandir` example are essentially the below type hacks?

```py
import re
def isinstance_from_type(x, class_info):
    _chunk = re.search("(?<=\s['|\"]).*?(?=['|\"])", str(type(x)),re.DOTALL)
    try:
        return _chunk.group(0) == str(class_info)
    except:
        return False

>>> a = scandir.scandir("/home")
>>> type(a) == "scandir.ScandirIterator"
False

>>> isinstance_from_type(a, "scandir.ScandirIterator")
True
```

Okay I get why i don't get a string back from calling `type` etc, but please let me know if there's a better, more universal and consistent method i simply don't know, or the *hot and dangerous* things that are coming using a `regex`; trust me.. i get it.

Thanks for reading and any/all feedback about the mechanics of this specific to python are welcomed.

Comment: It is extremely straightforward. The way is to **use `isinstance` or `type` but you have to actually provide the type**.  You did `isinstance(df, (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame))` but `pandas` **is not defined**... why did you *think* it was defined? You had *just used `pd.DataFrame` to *create your dataframe using the constructor*, use `isinstance(df,  pd.DataFrame)`

Comment: i think you're missing the question, or... i didn't make it clear in mine

Comment: What is it that isn't clear?

Comment: maybe a better question is, whats a straightforward, and universal method of accessing and validating the "type" of an object. I feel like python is a bit convoluted (why i outlined with another language) when it comes to this, OR I am missing a very simple concept under the hood and am hoping someone points that out and it clicks.

Comment: What do you mean? What isn't straightforward about `pd.DataFrame`? Note, I have no idea what library you are using, for me, if I install scandir, and use `type(a)` i get generator, not a `posix.ScandirIterator`

Comment: Right, so going with that; whats the next _inexpensive_ step to validating something is a generator as you would if it were an instance of `list` or `str` etc

Comment: Is your question actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416538/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-a-generator-object-in-python ?

Comment: Generally, you don't do this. The generator type can etiher be retrieved using something like `generator = type(i for i in range(1))` or `import types` and use `types.GeneratorType`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille that helps, I can go through the source code to get a better grasp of what's going on there. juanpa.arrivillaga appreciate the input. Thanks, all.

Comment: @CarlBoneri the source code? No! If you check the `types` module, you'll find `GeneratorType = type(_g())` where `_g` is just a generator defined like `def _g(): yield 1`. Not all the types used by a library will necessarily be exposed. Sometimes, you have to dig in to a library. Or, you can just create an object of that type and use `type`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga cool!

Comment: And don't ever use your `isinstance_from_type`